# jQuery: How to setup gmap.js

Tags: jquery, google-maps, jquery-plugins, dictionary

I am not able to set up gmap.js
I try to google the whole morning but now i am forced to ask to StackOverflow.

I replicate here what i am trying to do to setup a basic map:
http://jsfiddle.net/Cfbaa/

Basically i start calling:

```
- JQuery
- Google map API
- gmap.js (taken from github repo)
- css file (taken from github repo)
```

Then i call the div for the simple map:

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

And initialize jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var map = new GMaps({
        div: '#map',
        lat: 51.5073346,
        lng: -0.1276831,
    });
});
```

Can you tell me please what is wrong there, or what is missing?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have setup into gmap example into jsBin

http://jsbin.com/aTOlOGU

Please have look, its working perfectly

I think, jsFiddle hasn't load Google map script properly

Comment: Thank you man.
Is the whole the day i am hitting my head against the wall, and now it worked just smoothly..